# Please translate this line to me

Tags: css

```
<style>
    body .bPageBlock .pbBody .red .pbSubheader {
        background-color:#cA0BBC;
    }
    body .bPageBlock .pbBody .grey .pbSubheader {
        background-color:#c0c0c0;
    }
</style>
```

How do you read this? is this read as: pbSubheader inside red inside pbBody...etc?

Later in the code, the author uses

```
styleClass="red"
```

I don't understand it.

Comment: Yes, your reading is correct. You should probably study CSS a bit before making changes. I am not sure what syntax `styleClass="red"` is though

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357211/multiple-classes-in-css-selector

Comment: Thanks. The    styleClass="red" is what is used in Salesforce VisualForce page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an effort to supply an answer to the question (rather than a comment):

Your selector identifies an element or elements with class `pbSubheader` inside
an element with class `red` inside
an element with class `pbBody` inside
an element with class `bPageBlock` inside
the `body` element.